# Android Studio will not open after clear cache/invalidate

Tags: android-studio, macos-catalina, macbookpro-touch-bar

My Android Studio was running slow on my Macbook so I cleared cache and invalidated. When attempting to relaunch the app, it would animate like it was going to open but then just stopped. I waited several minutes and still no luck. I deleted the app and all the folders and reinstalled and I got the same result. I restarted my Mac and still have the same result.

**Edit:**

My 2018 15inch MacbookPro is running macOS Catalina version 10.15.1 (latest)

Comment: Hi @QThompson could you please tell more detail about your Macbook specially about system specification?

Comment: how much RAM and secondary storage  space available ?